# vim windows does not display char $ with utf-8. distinguish from vim encoding problem and windows10 openssh server problem

Tags: vim, utf-8, windows-10, openssh

I need to use the utf-8 encoding. With this option vim does not display `$` symbol, but `||` instead. How can I get vim to properly display `$`?

**UPDATE:** 
  `VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled May 18 2018 18:26:56) 
    MS-Windows 32-bit console version
host 64 win 10 pro OpenSSH.Server

Client ssh ubuntu 18.04`

the problem persist if only i do ssh to host and run vim. Locally all chars displayed normally.

below image of typed `$` and `a command`

[image]

Comment: Can you use `ga` on the characters and see what codes it reports?

Comment: the code is 206 and not 36 as normally code is

Comment: does code 206 means something wrong with console?

Comment: Probably an encoding or keyboard issue would be my guess